# Next and previous button not visible in fancybox jquery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

jquery

```
$(".gallery_bg").fancybox({//displaying images

        /*openEffect    : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        'cyclic':'true',
        'scrolling':'yes',
        'showNavArrows':'true',
        helpers : {
            title : {
                type : 'inside'
            }
        }
    */
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
    showNavArrows        : true,
    closeBtn        : false,
    helpers     : { 
        title   : { type : 'inside' },
        buttons : {}
    }

    });
```

i have included the style.css

```
#fancybox-left-ico {
left: 20px;
}

#fancybox-right-ico {
right: 20px;
left: auto;
}
```

after including too i am not able to see the next and previous icon?

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/dudesays/h7NGK/2/)

Comment: make a fiddle please... on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: okies will add to jsfiddle.net

Comment: @diEcho  have added the jsfiddle.net link.....

Comment: guys, fiddle won't help, since we need to see all the fancybox dependencies (images,css-files and so on). Create a demopage plz WITH (working?) close button on your own webspace!

Comment: @dude i edited my answer, check the 3 points, this should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure that the `fancybox_sprite.png` file in in **the same folder** than the `jquery.fancybox.css` file.

If you want to display the next/prev arrows permanently, not on mouse hover only, then use this inline `css` (after you loaded/linked to the `jquery.fancybox.css` file)

```
<style type="text/css">
 .fancybox-next span {
  left: auto;
  right: 20px;
 }
 .fancybox-prev span {
  left: 20px;
 }
</style>
```

**Note**: this is for fancybox v2.x (which I assumed you are using because the options you are using in your script)

Answer (score 5):

On the anchor tag that the user clicks on in your html page, make sure you include rel="group" within the anchor tag. This should automatically pull in the next and previous buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I have tip simple tips but it works for me. You have to add rel="gallery1".

```
<a class="fancybox" href="images/product2_big.jpg" rel="gallery1"><img src="images/open-icon.png" alt="" /></a>
<a class="fancybox" href="images/product2_big.jpg" rel="gallery1"><img src="images/open-icon.png" alt="" /></a>
```

I hope everyone can fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

On your Testpage:

1. check if jquery.fancybox.js and fancybox.css are included properly (no Type-Exception: no method "fancybox" for this object)
2. examine your code to see if the pictures are loaded (path-errors in your css, typos...)
3. check, if your arrows are correctly positioned (display, visibility, position left, right...)

I'm sure, It's one of the 3 things above.

Comment: ya i am sure that that icons and path are correct ... as the close button appears from the same folder

Comment: Please provide a demo page for further help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue but i had to add data-fancybox-group='1' to get the buttons to show up automagically

Answer (score 0):

This is an old issue, but I recently had a problem with Fancybox3 not showing the close, next, and previous buttons. I had the necessary CSS and JS files included, in the proper order, and my JS configuration was correct (no JS errors).

To fix the issue I had to add `data-fancybox="gallery"` to my anchor (`<a>`) tags.