# fancybox no navigation buttons for video gallery

Tags: jquery, navigation, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using fancybox for some youtube videos and I would like to have navigation buttons (next and previous buttons beside the overlay) exactly like in [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/fhpZ5/) fiddle.

Here is my fancybox:

```
$('.fancybox-media')
    .attr('rel', 'playlist')
    .fancybox({
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        prevEffect: 'none',
        nextEffect: 'none',
        arrows: false,

        helpers: {
            media: {}
        },
        overlay : {
            css: { 'overflow-y': 'hidden' }
        },
        youtube : {
            autoplay: 1,
            hd: 1,
            wmode: 'opaque',    // shows X to close
            vq: 'hd720'         // default 720p hd quality
        },
        beforeShow : function(){
            $("body").css("overflow", "hidden"); // hide body scrollbar
        },
        afterClose: function(){
            $("body").css("overflow", "scroll"); // show body scrollbar
        }
    });
```

Regarding to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172832/next-and-previous-button-not-visible-in-fancybox-jquery) post from JFK, I've put these styles in my css file:

```
.fancybox-lock {
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.fancybox-nav {
    width: 60px;       
}

.fancybox-nav span {
    visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-next {
    right: -60px;
}

.fancybox-prev {
    left: -60px;
}
```

and my html:

```
<li class="closed">Headline
    <ul>
        <li class="fl"><a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dtb5Srdx7iY" rel="playlist"><img class="thumbnail" src="x.jpg"></a></li>
        <li class="fl"><a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dtb5Srdx7iY" rel="playlist"><img class="thumbnail" src="x.jpg"></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and the implemented stylesheets:

```
 <!-- FancyBox -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4" media="screen" />
```

I just can't get this to work and I don't know why. I feel like I am missing some files or so.

Comment: why not post your code in a jsfiddle and if it doesnt work post the link here...

Comment: have you checked the accepted answer in question you linked? have you tried to debug it with firebug net tab to check if indeed you are missing any files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172832/next-and-previous-button-not-visible-in-fancybox-jquery) by JFK (me) is more than one year old so that accepted answer might be overruled by the latest versions of fancybox so you should forget about it by now.

The only css you need is the same as in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhpZ5/) that you refer at begining of your post :

```
.fancybox-nav {
    width: 60px;       
}

.fancybox-nav span {
    visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-next {
    right: -60px;
}

.fancybox-prev {
    left: -60px;
}
```

...then, your jQuery code doesn't need these lines so you can remove them

```
overlay : {
    css: { 'overflow-y': 'hidden' }
}
beforeShow : function(){
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden"); // hide body scrollbar
},
afterClose: function(){
    $("body").css("overflow", "scroll"); // show body scrollbar
}
```

... since that is already handle by fancybox v2.1.4

Last, since you said `I would like to have navigation buttons (next and previous buttons beside the overlay)`, then it doesn't make sense to have this option in your code,

```
arrows: false
```

...does it? so remove it too. See working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xheWQ/)**

Comment: This seems to make sense :P Thank you! One last thing: I tried to show the arrows permanently as you described in your fiddle, but I don't know where to put the inline style. My html pages only are <article>...</article> that I load into my #content in order not having to reload the page everytime I click on a link. So I removed the css from my style.css and pasted the inline style in the header of my index.html and above one of my linked <article> page, but none of this worked.

Comment: @JFK: Tried to apply your fiddle, its not working for me, i included jquery.fancybox.js/css. The links are direclty going to youtube. Can u please help me in this.

Comment: @Rosh : what do you mean with is not working for you: the visible nav arrows? ... an wonder how come I can help you if I don't know your code or your working site.